# Unsupervised learning with bags of words with a word metric

Tags: classification, clustering, bag-of-words

I would like to perform clustering on a collection of documents with the assumption that I have a metric $\rho$ which tells me how close two words are to being synonyms.

If $\mathcal{W}$ is our vocabulary and if $\mathcal{D}$ is our universe of documents, I would like to find an appropriate function $\theta:\mathcal{D}\to \mathbb{R}^m$ and a pseudometric $D$ on $\mathbb{R}^m$ so that our clustering can work to minimize some objective in terms of the intra/intercluster distances of the form $D(\theta(d_1), \theta(d_2))$.

One on hand, the function $\theta$ and the metric $D$ should take $\rho$ into account. So if we have three one-word documents $d_i=\{w_i\}$ for $i=1,2,3$, if $\rho(w_1,w_2)$ is small and $\rho(w_1,w_3)$ is large, then $D(\theta(d_1), \theta(d_2))$ should be smaller than $D(\theta(d_1), \theta(d_3))$.

On the other hand, $D$ should not completely ignore vector similarity. So, for example, if $d_1=(w_1)$ and $d_2=(w_1 w_1\ldots w_1)$, $D(\theta(d_1), \theta(d_2))$ should not be too large.

Are there standard approaches for how to perform this kind of clustering?